# TimeZone don't work in Android

Tags: android, calendar

1. I want to set my calender timezone to paris by default but calender takes my pc time.
2. I want to convert `currentDate` to `TimeStamp.`

   How can i do that. here is my workings.

   //GET UNIX TIME

   ```
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2"));
            String currTime = String.valueOf(c.getTime());
            Date requestDate = formatter.parse(currTime);
            Calendar requestDateCal = formatter.getCalendar();
            requestDateCal.setTime(requestDate);

            String currentTime=String.valueOf(requestDateCal.getTimeInMillis());

            System.out.println("date : "+ currentTime);
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the timestamp is the same for all the time zones, and if you want to print your calendar in other timezone just do this:

```
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("date : " + formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
```

and to get the calendar time zone do this:

```
    cal.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
```

Thanks